# Selenium, mocha, mysql. Mysql operation order

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I'm using selenium with mocha and node-mysql for my test. But get into the throuble. Looks like part of my code execute mysql query before test manipulations:

mysqlfunc.js

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection =     mysql.createConnection('here is my connection url');

    exports.countNums = function countNumbers(phone, user, callback){
 connection.query('Here is SELECT', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;

  
      callback(rows[0]['COUNT(*)']); 
  
    });
    connection.end();
    };
```

And test.js:

```js
var wd = require('selenium-webdriver');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var phonelist = require('./mysqlfunc.js')

var SELENIUM_HOST = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
var URL = 'myurl.com';

var client = new wd.Builder()
   .usingServer(SELENIUM_HOST)
   .withCapabilities({ browserName: 'firefox' })
   .build();


  
client.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);


suite('Blacklists');

test('adding to blacklist', function(done){


 
  client.get(URL);
 client.findElement({ name: 'username' }).sendKeys('autolistmanageuser');
 client.findElement({ name: 'password' }).sendKeys('autolistmanageuser');
    client.findElement({ id: 'login-button' }).click();
 client.findElement({ linkText: 'Black list' }).click();
 client.sleep(2000) 
 client.findElement({ linkText: 'Addnum' }).click();
     
 
 client.findElement({ xpath: '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/input' }).sendKeys('79265914970');
 client.findElement({ xpath: '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/label[1]/input[@value="1"]' }).click();
 
 
 client.findElement({ xpath: '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/button' }).click()
 
//HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!! Looks like countNums executing before all the selenium code above then result is 1
phonelist.countNums('79265914970','autolistmanageuser', function(result) {
  
  assert.equal(0, result, 'Number was not deleted');
 
  done();
 },done);
});
```

The problem in phonelist.countNums that returns wrong value as it was executed before the selenium manipulations
The selenium code deletes phone number using web page
phonelist.countNums - select count(*) from Mysql occurrences of the deleted number, so I'm waiting for 0

Answer (score 0):

Scince everything is async and my phonelist.countNums does not get in to flowcontrol of webdriver and starts in parallel with webriver.
So solution is to enqueue into webdriver order:

```js
client.isElementPresent({ linkText: 'pages 2600' }).then(function(result) {
        
  phonelist.countNums('79265914970','autolistmanageuser', function(date) {
  console.log('external ' +date);
  assert.equal(0, date, 'number is still present');
  });
  done();
 },done);
```

This works for me fine and i hope this is the right answer. Good luck!